# 2D Arrays in LUA not possible in loop?

Tags: arrays, loops, lua, nested, 2d

For some reason I've been stuck on this problem for ages. I can't work out how to define grid[i] without resetting all of it's values. I want to make it so the program checks to see if the point in the 2D array is already occupied then it wont place a block.

```
radius = 10

grid = {}

while true do
    for i = -radius,radius do
        grid[i] = {}
        for j = -radius,radius do
            if math.sqrt(math.pow(i,2)+math.pow(j,2))<radius and (not grid[i][j] or grid[i][j] == 0) then
                print("Placing..")
            else
                part:Destroy()
                grid[i][j] = 0
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: There is supposed to be a grid[i][j] = 1after print("Placing..")

Comment: I still havent managed to solve this.

Comment: `grid[i] = grid[i] or {}`

Comment: `math.pow(i,2)+math.pow(j,2)<math.pow(radius, 2)` a power is easier to calculate than a square root, so this makes things faster :)

Comment: Also consider adding `local pow = math.pow` at the beginning and the just using `pow`. Same with other functions you use a lot. This reduces table lookups and makes code a bit faster.

Comment: In general, try reducing table lookups. `local pos = grid[i][j]; if not pos or pos == 0...`. Again, table lookups == evil when it comes to speed in lua.

Comment: Or to make it yet faster, use multiplication: `i * i + j * j < radius * radius`.

Answer (score 0):

```
radius = 10

grid = {}

while true do
    for i = -radius,radius do
        grid[i] = {}
--      ^ This line here!
        for j = -radius,radius do
            if math.sqrt(math.pow(i,2)+math.pow(j,2))<radius and (not grid[i][j] or grid[i][j] == 0) then
                print("Placing..")
            else
                part:Destroy()
                grid[i][j] = 0
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Your code resets the grid because that's exactly what you tell it to do. Every time you iterate the outer table, you reset each of its values to a new (empty) table.

I assume you only want to add a new table if there isn't one already; this can be achieved with

```
grid[i] = grid[i] or {}
```

In other words, "set grid[i] to grid[i] if it has a value, or to {} otherwise". The first one doing nothing and the second creating a new row only if one didn't exist already. This is a pretty common Lua idiom.

It should be noted though that this code has a lot of potential for optimizing. [Here](https://www.lua.org/gems/sample.pdf)'s a PDF describing in depth the most common ways one can improve speed of Lua code and [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/OptimisationCodingTips) is a more beginner-friendly list if you don't want to read an entire paper on the topic :)